# Visual Studio 11 Web Test with different paths

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, webtest, web-testing, microsoft-test-manager

I'm trying to create a Web test in Visual Studio 11 beta. The problem is that the app can randomly serve different pages to the user (something like an A/B test).

That is user journey can be pages:

> A > B > C > D > E

or :

> A > F > G > H > D > E

Is there a way to handle this without going to a coded test?

Comment: Need more information... are there only two possible pages at each step, or many? Can the pages repeat during the journey, or do they only display once? Do the pages have different URLs or just different content? If the latter, how do you tell the pages apart? To move to the next page is the request always the same or does it differ? Is there some specific reason you have to know which page was served? If the same request(s) can be used to move from page to page and the pages aren't materially different, the solution is trivial. Otherwise the solution will be somewhat complex.